# Running multiple adb commands with python Popen or os.system

Tags: android, python, adb

One problem with ADB is that you need multiple commands to get things done.
For example:

```
adb shell

su 

cp /data/local/x /data/local/y

exit

adb pull /data/local/y
```

Can this be done using python popen and os-system? Tried the example below without success..

```
print 'Starting emulator...'
subprocess.Popen(['emulator', '-avd', 'testavd'])
os.system('adb wait-for-device')
os.system('Perform whatever adb commands you need')
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
adb shell su -c cp /data/local/x /data/local/y
adb pull /data/local/y
```

or, if you want to run more than one command (only Linux & OSX):

```
adb shell <<EOF
ls
date
cat /proc/version
exit
EOF
```

Comment: I would need to find a way to do this on Windows ... maybe cygwin?

Comment: type script.txt | adb shell; maybe ?